# Is there a plausible outline of how geometric complexity theory could prove $P \neq NP$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-complexity

I've heard people saying that geometric complexity theory could be the key to showing $P \neq NP$, but when I've actually read about it it seems like it's concerned with other, perhaps analogous classes, such as $VP$, $VNP$, etc.  Is there an actual research program which would, in principle, allow the $P$ vs $NP$ problem to be resolved using geometric complexity theory, or could it at best solve some related problems giving some heuristic information about $P$ vs $NP$?